# Is my ISP throttling Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, 13.04, networking, connection, macbook

today I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my MacBook Air. I noticed that the internet speed (as well as torrent, direct download and wget speed) is no more than 50kb/s... I have another PC in the house and the speed is the same. Assuming I have a 20**MByte**/s connection speed and on my MacBook with OS X the speed was always around **1MBit**/s, how can this be possible? I noticed also a big SLOW DOWN in loading pages (I think this is related to my internet speed being throttled). ON MY NEXUS 4, THE SPEED IS ALWAYS 700KBit/s so it is not a modem issue... I think this is related to Ubuntu.. Thank for help, Lorenzo

**EDIT:** Dennis helped me find out that I had so me ports blocked and using Gufw I opened them. Thank you Dennis!

Comment: You should test if really you are being throttled, or change ISP. Anyways, we cannot help you there as is not something that you need to solve with Ubuntu but with your ISP.

Comment: Based on the answer you accepted, it appears you had modified some firewall settings away from their default values and then noticed the problem. Is that correct? If so, please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the ports are closed. You can install gufw and open up the ports through the gui interface.

```
sudo apt-get install gufw
```

On a parallel observation, if you have a 20MB connection your download speed should be 2.4Mbps.